# Find an element in a collection of collection

Tags: .net, linq

How to use Linq to find an item in a List of ProductCat where every ProductCat contains a List of Product.

I want to find the Product by ProductID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product foundProduct = productCatList
            .SelectMany(list => list.Products)
            .Where(product => product.ProductID == whateverID)
            .SingleOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var results = from pc in myProductCats
              where pc.Products.Contains(ProductId)
              select pc;
```

You question is missing a lot of details.  If you provide some code and the class structure I can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure Linq language syntax:

```
  var pds = from pc in prodCats
            select from p in pc.Products where p.ProductID < 3
            select p;
```

But I think the IEnumerable extension + lambda version is more readable.